# Product of non-disjoint k-cycles

Tags: permutations

I have two $k$-cycles $\alpha=(a \dots c \dots b \dots)$ and $\beta=(a \dots b \dots c \dots)$ and $\alpha \neq \beta^{-1}$. How to show that the product $\alpha \beta$ does not result in a cyclic permutation (just one cycle permutation).

Or, perhaps it has a counter example.

Thanks.

Comment: Without further assumptions, yes indeed: $(1,2,3)(1,3,2)=id$.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. Actually, I have forgotten to add the assumption that $\alpha \neq \beta^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, @N.S. has already provided another example, but that is a superficial restriction. For example $(1,2,3,4)(1,3,2) = [(4,1)(1,2,3)](1,3,2) = (4,1)id=(4,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan Y. Dou you think it is possible that product could result in another k-cycle? –

Comment: Certainly: $(1,2,3,4,5)(1,3,5,2,4)=(1,4,2,5,3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1,4,2,3)(1,4,3,2)=(1,3,4) \,.$$

To find the example I just picked two 4-cyles in $S_4$, and made sure that 1 doesn't end in a 2-cycle. Note that in $S_4$ the only non-cyclic permutations are the products of two $2$-cycles.